# CGContext is not drawing my shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgcontext, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to draw a hexagon in a `UIView`. I do this by overriding the `drawRect` method in my subclass of `UIView`.
But when the view is shown I only see the `backgroundColor` of the `view` but I don't see my shape being drawn in it.

This is the code in my `-drawRect` method

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([_fillColor CGColor]));

    NSArray *points = _hex.points;

    CGPoint point = [points[0] CGPointValue];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);

    for (int i = 1; i < [points count]; i++){
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    }


    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
```

The array that is being drawn is the following:

```
  NSMutableArray *mutablePoints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:6];
    [mutablePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(40, 0)]];
    [mutablePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(59, 0)]];
    [mutablePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(68.5, 16.4544)]];
    [mutablePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(59, 32.9089)]];
    [mutablePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(40, 32.9089)]];
    [mutablePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(30.5, 16.4544)]];
```

Comment: sure of `setNeedsDisplay`?

Comment: When I run the app and add a breakpoint in the drawRect method I can see that the code is called, so I suggest that setNeedsDisplay was called.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :** you forgot online in for loop look this code

```
  for (int i = 1; i < [points count]; i++) {

        point = [points[i] CGPointValue]; // YOU FORGOT !

        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide your point array please so, i can implement it

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the point in yoour loop !
Just add:

point = [points[i] CGPointValue]

inside your loop ?